# Passing data from HTML page to PHP script

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

So I currently have a PHP script that is being called from an HTML link.  The script is set up such that it needs to accept non-user input from the page (static data that already exists).  The line that calls the script looks like this.

```
<div class="Name"><a href="some/script">Text</a></div>
```

I need to pass the values in "Name" and Text to the script, as well as another value from an earlier line.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  All of my research points to using forms and GET/POST, but as you can see, there is no place for the user to input any of the data.  Is there any way to do this using hidden forms or AJAX?

Comment: GET and POST don't necessarily need to rely on user-input data. You don't need to use AJAX

Comment: Question is not clear (to me at least). I assume you are trying to pull data from a referring HTML page without being able to modify that page. Can you modify the html page? Is the HTML page itself dynamically generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code well help

```
<div class="Name"><a id="link" href="some/script.php">Text</a></div>
<input id="name" onblur="modify(this.value)">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = document.getElementById("link").href;
    var modify = function(name){
        var a = document.getElementById("link");
        a.href = link + "?name="+name;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're the author of the web page, you'd use javascript and an onclick event to capture the div class and the anchor's text, and send it via ajax (or directly if your script provides some sort of user output or redirect back to the calling page) to your script as a post event. the data could be conveniently formatted as a json structure to simplify the script's processing.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `GET` method :

```
<div class="Name"><a href="some/script?name1=value1&name2=value2">Text</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `href` attribute for the link, do something like this:

```
href="some/script?name=George&text=All This Stuff"
```

This will make the information available in the `$_GET[]` array in the PHP script.